# Best Practice to Safely Migrate Database in SailsJS App when using Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, security, sails.js

I have an application developed with SailsJS and mysql. Only a logged in user is meant to be able to create a fresh user. During development stage, I made creation of the first user easy with a simple request to server. That is however not feasible again as I have written some policy codes to prevent such.

```js
module.exports= async function(req, res, proceed){
    const adminId = req.param('adminId');
    if(!adminId){
        return res.status(401).json({status: 401, message: 'Unauthorized access, invalid user'});
    }
    //let's check if the user has a role as superadmin
    const superAdmin = await Admin.findOne({id: adminId, superAdmin: true});
    console.log(superAdmin)
    if(superAdmin){
        return proceed();
    }
    else{
        return res.status(401).json({status: 401, message: "Unauthorized access. You don't have this privilege"})
    }
    
}
```

Also, Every saved new user has a compulsory createdBy column in mysql database.

I currently want to host the project on production. What best way should I do this. By default, I am supposed to run

```js
sails lift --prod
```

On production environment and generate the mysql tables. However, I won't be able to login or create an admin user. So what is the best way for me to create a new user?

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way is obviously subjective.  Personally I would write a migration to bootstrap the DB with the first production user (you are using migrations, right?).

Some people eschew including [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) in their migrations, although in my experience at some point in the long lifetime of an application under development, some type of "data fixup" needs to happen.  Doing it as idempotently as possible in a migration has been the easiest and most reliable approach.